# Link an azure function app authentication to an app registration under a different Tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

I'm currently trying to setup authentication for an Azure function app. However when I attempt to link the "app registration" id - it complains as the api is not under the same tenant as the App Registration.

I'm following this Microsoft Azure B2C documentation [Configure the backend application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c)

I understand what the error is, but is there any way around this?

Application with ID xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx not found in the current tenant. Tenant ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.

Kia Kaha,

Mike Smith

Comment: If it is a single tenant app, then we don't have any way around. you can make/Create app registration as multi-tenant application and give a try. please check this for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25329/how-to-access-an-api-registered-as-multi-tenantten.html

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check whether multi-tenant option is enabled in Azure or not as below: -

portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Select Your App -> Authentication -> Supported account types -> Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)

•   The above option should be enabled when you want to allow public users as below. If you are wanting to authorize the user into organization level (Private Users). Use the below option: -

let authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
change like below:

let authUrl= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_NAME"

[image: Azure AD Multitenant potion]

•   Please refer the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-sign-into-app

["Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant" when signing into my Azure website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526121/use-a-tenant-specific-endpoint-or-configure-the-application-to-be-multi-tenant)