# Microsoft Graph Toolkit: "Use a tenant-specific endpoint"

Tags: html, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-web-app

As expected, my code is very simple. I have the script reference, the `mgt-msal2-provider` element with my client-id specified, and a simple login `<mgt-login></mgt-login>`.

IF I set up my app in the Azure portal to be "multitenant", everything works. However, I do *not want* this publicly available.  How do I specify a tenant using the simple methods above? I found [questions that talk about specifying a tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526121/use-a-tenant-specific-endpoint-or-configure-the-application-to-be-multi-tenant), but I don't know how to specify it since I'm not using any javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/msal2#initialize-in-your-html-page), please try by adding `authority` attribute to `mgt-msal2-provider` and set its value to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[your-tenant-id]`.